# adding or returning an expression dynamically to python

Tags: python

I want a special decorator or even changing python internally, so that the following could be possible:

```
@special_decorator
def fo():
    pass

fo()  # transform to " yield fo() "
```

Comment: use `lambda` ? return function not function calls? unclear. XY problem?

Comment: You may no need to return on your `fo2` function.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i tried lamda but i can't yield in lamda

Comment: @FrankAK the return is to explain my self i will remove it

Comment: How to you want to call your function which you declare above? Can you also explain why you need this? where to use it?

Comment: @FrankAK image that fo3 is a function that handle a request . so it may call other functio and some may be blocking , so i have a special decorator "save_context" and whe i use that decorator and yield , the webserver can continue doing his job and restore context when blocking call is finished where i put yield . so i dont want to put yield everywhere but i special decorator wich will replace all blocking call with a yield fo() when the caller call fo()

Comment: well! I guess you may want to declare a function like a callback function, you can use tornado or aync wait (python 3.x) support it

Comment: i am alrady using a anyc library but i don't wanna end up with callback everywhere . that why i use yield

Comment: try gevent if you want to make you async program code like sync structure!

Comment: @FrankAK look at the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this decorator:

```
def to_yield(f):
    def inner():
        yield f()
    return inner
```

Testing

```
@to_yield
def foo():
    return 'called foo'


print(next(foo())
# prints "called foo"
```

Comment: the thing is i can juste write yield foo() but that what i want to automate. i want to the yield to happen in the caller

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more clear about what you are asking and post an example. What do you mean you want a "yield in the caller"? What caller? I think you need to post an example because right now this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: image that fo3 is a function that handle a request . so it may call other functio and some may be blocking , so i have a special decorator "save_context" and whe i use that decorator and yield , the webserver can continue doing his job and restore context when blocking call is finished where i put yield . so i dont want to put yield everywhere but i special decorator wich will replace all blocking call with a yield fo() when the caller call fo()